# MySQL select before after row

Tags: mysql, row, surround

This is the example table:

```
Column             | 1st record | 2nd record | 3rd record | 4th record | etc<br />
id (primary)       | 1          | 5          | 8          | 12         | etc<br />
name               | name 1     | name 2     | name 3     | name 4     | etc<br />
date               | date 1     | date 2     | date 3     | date 4     | etc<br />
callValue (unique) | val1       | val2       | val3       | val4       | etc
```

I select one row that is the data to show (for example: row with callValue: val3). But I cannot find a solution for this:
I need to select previous and next row. So, in this example, I need to get data from rows callValue: val4 and callValue: val2, or id: 5 and id: 12.

It cannot be done with `id`=`id`+-1 because `id` doesn't have to be continuous because of deleting rows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you have the id `8`, you should be able to do a variation on:

```
select * from mytable
where id < 8
order by id desc
limit 1
```

and:

```
select * from mytable
where id > 8
order by id asc
limit 1
```

for the previous and next record.

Comment: this solution is shorter and better to understand for everyone.

Comment: how do you know it's better for everyone ? you probably mean it was better for your self.

Comment: It's shorter, it uses simpler syntax, it's more readable, and has superior performance. I think it's safe to say it is better overall.

Comment: @JureŠpik, come on, it's clearly that it's better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, but it was not "better for everyone" since for me the other answer was better.

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
select * from test where callValue = 'val3'  
union all  
(select * from test where callValue < 'val3' order by id desc limit 1) 
union all  
(select * from test where callValue > 'val3' order by id asc limit 1)
```

or

```
select * from test where id = 8
union all  
(select * from test where id < 8 order by id desc limit 1) 
union all  
(select * from test where id > 8 order by id asc limit 1)
```

Comment: First I received error message, but putting () after union solved it :)

Comment: Welcome! I'm not very good with mysql-specific syntax, sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.date, a.callValue 
FROM
(
    select @r0 := @r0 + 1 as rownum, id, name, date, callValue from TABLE
    , (SELECT @r0 := 0) r0
) a,
(
    select @r1 := @r1 + 1 rownum, id, name, date, callValue from TABLE
    , (SELECT @r1 := 0) r1 
) b
where b.callValue = val3 and b.rownum between (a.rownum-1 and a.rownum+1)
```

It expands the table into 2 dimensions so you can compare the rows in the fist table to any set of rows from the second.

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from callvalue
where id <  maxd
(
select max(id) as maxd
from callvalue
where id = maxd
)
```