# PHP and MySQL show for before position

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Mysql database, where the records are sorted by positions. How do I display. The data that is before a position, and not show the data of the following positions?

**PHP invoke data**

```
$r_ruta = $_GET["r_ruta"]; 
$jornada = $_GET["jornada"]; 
$query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * '.
                            'FROM escolar '.
                            "WHERE r_ruta = '$r_ruta' ".
                              "AND jornada = '$jornada' ".
                            'ORDER BY pos ASC');
```

Comment: are referring to `BETWEEN` operator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select before after row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836279/mysql-select-before-after-row)

Comment: describe elaborate what  your want.

Comment: I need to show the coordinates related to my id, and the one that is before and the previous id, only those two data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using above query, you will get this id, say $id. Then next query for previous id can be like this -

```
        $query = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * '.
                            'FROM escolar '.
                            "WHERE id < '$id' ".
                            'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1');
```